# Como criar um markdown simples com PHP?

Tags: php, regex

Gostaria de criar um markdown simples, para negrito e itálico por enquanto apenas, por exemplo:

- `**foo**` vira `<b>foo</b>`
- `__bar__` vira `<i>bar</i>`

Claro que alguns detalhes são necessários, por exemplo em itálico isto não pode funcionar:

```
 __ foo __
```

Pois está separado, a primeira e a última letra devem ser grudadas aos **"delimitadores"**, no entanto isso seria válido:

```
 __foo bar__     => <i>foo bar</i>
 __f o o b a r__ => <i>f o o b a r</i>
```

Pois espaços entre a primeira a última letra são aceitos.

No momento eu criei isto:

- Negrito:

  ```
  $str = preg_replace('#(^|[^\*])\*\*([^\s\*]([^\*]+?)?[^\s\*])\*\*([^\*]|$)#', '$1<b>$2</b>$4', $str);
  ```
- Italico:

  ```
  $str = preg_replace('#(^|[^_])__([^\s_]([^_]+?)?[^\s_])__([^_]|$)#', '$1<i>$2</i>$4', $str);
  ```

Ambas são bem semelhantes e parecem funcionar bem, para explicar melhor a regex:

```
(^|[^_])__([^\s_]([^_]+?)?[^\s_])__([^_]|$)

  ^     ^   ^     ^        ^     ^   ^
  |     |   |     |        |     |   |
  |     |   |     |        |     |   |
  |     |   |     |        |     |   |
  |     |   |     |        |     |   |
  |     |   |     |        |     |   +-- verifica se após o delimitador não é underscore ou se é o final da string
  |     |   |     |        |     |
  |     |   |     |        |     +-- verifica se o delimitador são 2 underscores
  |     |   |     |        |
  |     |   |     |        +-- o ultimo caractere antes do delimitador não pode ser espaço e nem underscore
  |     |   |     |
  |     |   |     +-- pega qualquer coisa que não seja underscore, esse grupo é opicional
  |     |   |
  |     |   +-- verifica se o que vem após o primeiro delimitador é diferente de espaço e diferente de underscore
  |     |
  |     +-- verifica se o delimitador são 2 underscores
  |
  +-- checa se é o começo da string ou se o que vem antes do delimitador é diferente de underscore _
```

Exemplo no ideone: https://ideone.com/PL8nTA

No entanto da forma que fiz a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) **não é possível** fazer isto:

```
__foo_bar__
```

E nem isto:

```
**foo*bar**
```

Gostaria de alguma sugestão de melhoria sobre isto ou até então algo totalmente diferente disto, mesmo que seja sem regex.

Comment: @sam não daria certo em uma frase com seguidos markdowns...

Comment: @MagicHat bem dito. Markdown não é regular, é livre de contexto.

Comment: @GuilehermeNascimento, necessita ser PHP? Nada de JS (sem usar biblioteca de terceiros)?

Comment: Li um tempo atrás sobre a especificação do Markdown ser [algo bem baguçando](https://philsturgeon.uk/markdown/2014/11/30/state-of-markdown/). Tirando a finalidade de estudos, não vejo muito o porque fazer isso considerando que existe uma quantidade [grande de parsers de markdown](https://packagist.org/?query=markdown) em PHP para usar/se inspirar.

Comment: @gmsantos eu sou uma pessoa que quero construir minhas proprias coisas por uma série de razões, se valer a pena construo, se não valer a pena não irei reinventar a roda, no caso aqui não sei se vale ou não a pena, fora que o meu objetivo é mais estudo do que soluções :)

Comment: O meu objetivo em responder é também em estudo. Não sou muito bom com regex e esta pergunta me ajudou a dar uma evoluída.

Answer (score 5):

A regex não aceita `__foo_bar__` por causa da [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^_]`, que corresponde a "qualquer caractere que **não** seja `_`". E como `foo_bar` tem um `_`, não é encontrado um *match*.

Para que aceite este caso, temos que incluir outra condição, que é "o caractere `_`, desde que não tenha outro `_` depois". Podemos fazer isso com um [*lookahead* negativo](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `_(?!_)`.

Sendo assim, este trecho ficaria `[^_]|_(?!_)` (um caractere que não é `_`, **ou** um `_` desde que não tenha outro `_` depois).

---

Outro detalhe é que a regex não aceita casos com somente um caractere entre os delimitadores, como por exemplo `__a__` ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/40PMF9/9/)). Isso é porque o `[^\s_]` aparece duas vezes: uma depois do delimitador inicial, e outra antes do delimitador final. Por isso a regex exige que haja pelo menos dois caracteres entre os delimitadores.

Podemos resolver isso usando um *lookahead* negativo logo depois do delimitador inicial: troco o `[^\s_]` por `(?![\s_])` (ou seja, não pode ter espaço nem `_` depois). A diferença é que o *lookahead* só olha o que tem à frente, mas não consome o caractere (então se tiver somente um, este será consumido pelos trechos seguintes da regex, permitindo o caso que só tem um caractere).

Também podemos trocar as verificações do início e fim para um *lookahead* e um *lookbehind*, para não criar grupos à toa e não precisar incluí-los na substituição. E por fim, deixar apenas um grupo de captura para o conteúdo entre os delimitadores, transformando os demais em [grupos de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap), trocando o `(` por `(?:`. Assim fico com somente um grupo, e na substituição posso fazer apenas `<i>$1</i>`.

Ficaria assim:

```
(?<=^|[^_])__((?![\s_])(?:(?:[^_]|_(?!_))+?)?[^\s_])__(?=[^_]|$)
```

<sup>*[Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/TVLK79/18) a regex funcionando*</sup>

Resumindo:

- `(?<=^|[^_])`: *lookbehind* para verificar se antes do delimitador tem o início da string ou um caractere que não seja `_`
- `(?![\s_])`: *lookahead* negativo para verificar se depois do delimitador não tem espaço nem `_`
- `[^_]|_(?!_)`: um caractere que não seja `_`, ou um `_` desde que não tenha outro `_` depois
- `[^\s_]`: um caractere que não é espaço nem `_`
- `(?=[^_]|$)`: *lookahead* para verificar se depois do delimitador tem o final da string ou um caractere que não seja `_`

Para os delimitadores `**`, basta usar a mesma lógica. Lembrando que o `*` possui significado especial em regex (é um [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) que indica "zero ou mais ocorrências") e deve ser escapado com `\` (ficando `\*`), exceto se estiver entre colchetes. Ou seja:

```
(?<=^|[^*])\*\*((?![\s*])(?:(?:[^*]|\*(?!\*))+?)?[^\s*])\*\*(?=[^*]|$)
```

Testando:

```
$q = "
Boa __tarde__ **Bacco**, isto é um **teste** com diversos **negritos** e __sublinhados__

__**um** dois__
**__um__ dois**

-- funciona
__foo bar__
__f o o b a r__
**teste __lorem ipsum__ dolor sit**
__teste **lorem ipsum** dolor sit__
abc__xyz__teste

-- não funcionava na primeira versão
__foo_bar__
__a__
__*__
__foo_*bar__


-- não é para funcionar
__ foo bar__
__foo bar __
_foo__
__ foo __
_foo_
__foo_
__ __
__a____
____a__
_____

-- corner case: aninhado (não tratei pois não sei o que deveria fazer)
__abc__xyz__123__
__abc __xyz__ 123__

-- corner case: escapes
__\___
__a\___
__\_abc__
";

$q = preg_replace('#(?<=^|[^*])\*\*((?![\s*])(?:(?:[^*]|\*(?!\*))+?)?[^\s*])\*\*(?=[^*]|$)#', '<b>$1</b>', $q);
$q = preg_replace('#(?<=^|[^_])__((?![\s_])(?:(?:[^_]|_(?!_))+?)?[^\s_])__(?=[^_]|$)#', '<i>$1</i>', $q);

var_dump($q);
```

Saída:

```
string(637) "
Boa <i>tarde</i> <b>Bacco</b>, isto é um <b>teste</b> com diversos <b>negritos</b> e <i>sublinhados</i>

<i><b>um</b> dois</i>
<b><i>um</i> dois</b>

-- funciona
<i>foo bar</i>
<i>f o o b a r</i>
<b>teste <i>lorem ipsum</i> dolor sit</b>
<i>teste <b>lorem ipsum</b> dolor sit</i>
abc<i>xyz</i>teste

-- não funcionava na primeira versão
<i>foo_bar</i>
<i>a</i>
<i>*</i>
<i>foo_*bar</i>


-- não é para funcionar
__ foo bar__
__foo bar __
_foo__
__ foo __
_foo_
__foo_
__ __
__a____
____a__
_____

-- corner case: aninhado (não tratei pois não sei o que deveria fazer)
<i>abc</i>xyz<i>123</i>
__abc <i>xyz</i> 123__

-- corner case: escapes
__\___
__a\___
<i>\_abc</i>
"
```

Como pode ver, ainda há *corner cases* a serem tratados:

- delimitadores aninhados: `__abc__xyz__123__` e `__abc __xyz__ 123__`, que foram substituídos respectivamente por `<i>abc</i>xyz<i>123</i>` e `__abc <i>xyz</i> 123__` (não sei como os *parsers* costumam tratar esses casos)
- escapes: `\_`deveria ser tratado com um caractere comum, por exemplo, `__a\___` deveria se tornar `<i>a_</i>` - [veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/IYyu8n/4/) uma tentativa frustrada de resolver, a solução definitiva creio que será bem mais complicada (tem uma bem complicada a seguir)

Enfim, o ideal é usar um *parser* de Markdown, [regex nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

---

Só para constar, segue uma alternativa para tratar os escapes:

```
$regex = '#(?<=^|[^_])__(?![\s_])(?=[^_])((?>[^\\\\_]*)(?>(?:(?>\\\\_)|(?>(?!__)_[^_]*))[^\\\\_]*)*)(?<![\s\\\\]|(?=\\\\)_)__(?=[^_]|$)#';
$q = preg_replace($regex, '<i>$1</i>', $q);
$q = preg_replace('/\\\\([*_])/', '$1', $q);
```

Começando pela segunda regex, que é mais fácil. Ela verifica se tem um `\` seguido de `_` ou `*`, e remove o `\`. Mas a complicada mesmo é a primeira, que verifica se tem um `_` escapado. Quebrando-a em partes (e colocando alguns espaços para ficar mais fácil de entender):

```
(?<=^|[^_]) __ (?![\s_])  <-- delimitador inicial
(?=[^_])  <-- verifica se tem pelo menos um caractere à frente (que não seja _)
(  <-- inicia grupo de captura (conteúdo que ficará entre as tags)
 (?> [^\\\\_]* )  <-- qualquer caractere que não seja _ nem \
 (?>
  (?:
    (?> \\\\_) |          <-- um escape (\_), ou
    (?> (?!__) _ [^_]* )  <-- um _ que não seja delimitador, seguido de caracteres que não são _
  )
  [^\\\\_]*   <-- qualquer caractere que não seja _ nem \
 )*
)
(?<![\s\\\\]|(?=\\\\)_) __(?=[^_]|$)  <-- delimitador final
```

Se quiser, você pode colocá-la no código da maneira acima, usando a *flag* `x` para que os espaços e quebras de linha sejam ignorados:

```
$regex = '#(?<=^|[^_]) __ (?![\s_])
(?=[^_])
(
 (?> [^\\\\_]* )
 (?>
  (?:
    (?> \\\\_) |
    (?> (?!__) _ [^_]* )
  )
  [^\\\\_]*
 )*
)
(?<![\s\\\\]|(?=\\\\)_) __(?=[^_]|$)#x';
```

Esta regex segue a técnica de [*unroll the loop*](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=89547), na qual você deve identificar as seguintes partes:

- delimitadores inicial e final: usei a mesma ideia da regex anterior, que é usar *lookaheads* e *lookbehinds* para verificar o que tem antes e depois do `__` (ou seja, verificar se não tem espaço depois do `__` inicial, etc). Só adicionei mais alguns casos para verificar se um dos `_` não está escapado com `\`
- "normal": o que acontece com mais frequência entre os delimitadores. No caso, são os caracteres que não sejam `\` nem `_`
- "especial": o que não é normal. No caso, é um escape (`\_`), ou um `_` sozinho (desde que não haja outro `_` depois)

A estrutura geral da regex é:

```
delimitador normal* (?:especial normal*)* delimitador
```

Como tanto o normal quanto o especial estão marcados com `*` (zero ou mais ocorrências), a regex aceitaria casos como `____`, então eu adicionei o *lookahead* `(?=[^_])` logo depois do delimitador inicial, para garantir que tem pelo menos um caractere.

Também são usados [grupos atômicos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) (marcados por `(?>`) para reduzir um pouco o *backtracking*.

Esta regex ignora os casos de escape (`\_`), mas não os remove, por isso precisei de outra regex para removê-los depois.

[Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/Bhyh92/3) esta regex funcionando. Apesar de funcionar, devem ter outros *corner cases* que ela não pega. Mas mesmo que não tivesse, ainda sim acho que não vale a pena, e usar um *parser* continua sendo a melhor opção.

Answer (score 3):

Depois de vários testes eu criei uma solução, que acredito irá contemplar todos os casos de string identificando as corretas e erradas. Para isso, eu parti da seguinte premissa:

**Casos que estão certos:**

Entrada:

```
__correto__
__c o r r e t o__
__c_o_r_r_e_t_o__
__cor   re  to__
__co rre _to__
__a__
```

Saída:

- *correto*
- *c o r r e t o*
- *c_o_r_r_e_t_o*
- *cor   re  to*
- *co rre _to*
- *a*

**Casos que estão errados:**

```
__errado __
__ errado__
__errado___
___errado__
```

Isso vale para os casos em **negrito**

Usando esta regex:

```
(.?)(__([^_\s]+\s*_?)*[^\s_]+__)([^_]|$)
```

junto com `preg_match_all`do PHP, podemos analisar os grupos da seguinte forma:

```
(.?) ---> pega qualquer caractere ou não, antes do próximo grupo

(__([^_\s]+\s*_?)*[^\s_]+__)  ([^_]|$) --> verifica se após o delimitador não é underline ou se é o final da string
^   ^             ^      ^
.   .             .      ----------> finaliza grupo com 2 underlines
.   .             .
.   .             ----------> pega um ou mais caracteres diferente de espaço e undeline
.   .
.   ------------------> este grupo pode ter ou não qualquer caractere seguido de 1 ou mais espaços(ou não) seguido de 1 underline(ou não)
.
----------------> inicia grupo com 2 underline
```

Com a ajuda do PHP, faremos isso:

```
    $string = "Boa __tarde__ **Bacco**, isto é um **teste** com diversos **negritos** e __sublinha_dos__

    __**um** dois__  **__um__ dois**
    __aqui nao_funciona __ __ nem_aqui,pois está errado__
    __aqui está certo__ ___errado__ __certo__";

    preg_match_all("/(.?)(\*\*([^\*\s]+\s*\*?)*[^\s\*]+\*\*)([^\*]|$)/", $string, $resultNegrito);

    $negrito = $resultNegrito[2];
    $iniNegrito = $resultNegrito[1]; // valores do grupo (.?)
    for($x = 0; $x < count($negrito); $x++){
        if($iniNegrito[$x] != "*"){
            $res = "<b>".substr($negrito[$x],2,strlen($negrito[$x]) -4)."</b>";
            $string = str_replace($negrito[$x],$res,$string);
        }
    }

    preg_match_all("/(.?)(__([^_\s]+\s*_?)*[^\s_]+__)([^_]|$)/", $string, $resultSublinhado);

   $sublinhado = $resultSublinhado[2];
    $iniSublinhado = $resultSublinhado[1]; // valores do grupo (.?)
    for($x = 0; $x < count($sublinhado); $x++){
        if($iniSublinhado[$x] != "_"){
            $res = "<u>".substr($sublinhado[$x],2,strlen($sublinhado[$x]) -4)."</u>";
            $string = str_replace($sublinhado[$x],$res,$string);
        }
    }

    echo $string;
```

**[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/9VJCR1)**

**ESCAPES..**

Neste script você consegue usar barras invertidas para criar textos sublinhados ou em negrito que estão fora do padrão. Imagine que usuário queira sublinhar isto: `__METHOD__` .Para isso, basta ele aplicar assim: `__\_\_METHOD_\_\__`

Usando o [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stripslashes.php) do PHP você retira as barras invertidas usadas deixando o texto limpo.

Um exemplo com o texto:

```
Para gerar um construtor nas recentes **\*versões do php*\**, 
usa-se o __**\_\_construct()**__ 
**esta é a __forma correta__** para usar. 

No **php** Existe a possibilidade de usar a 
contante mágica __\_\_FUNCTION_\_\__ para pegar o nome da função. 

__Neste script__, se eu quiser usar um **\*escape*\** para a 
barra inversa dentro de um sublinhado ou negrito, basta 
multiplica-lo por 3. Assim:

            __\\\_teste_\\\__
```

A saída usando `echo stripslashes($string)` será:

```html
Para gerar um construtor nas recentes <b>*versões do php*</b>, usa-se o <u><b>__construct()</b></u> <b>esta é a <u>forma correta</u></b> para usar. 

No <b>php</b> Existe a possibilidade de usar a contante mágica <u>__FUNCTION__</u> para pegar o nome da função. 

<u>Neste script</u>, se eu quiser usar um <b>*escape*</b> para a barra inversa dentro de um sublinhado ou negrito, basta multiplica-lo por 3. Assim:

<u>\_teste_\</u>
```

Comment: Caro Andrei, primeiro obrigado por responder, segundo, me desculpe mas preciso ser sincero, este uso do `_{1}` "não tem efeito", é o mesmo que sem ele, fora que não resolve o problema citado no final da pergunta. Irei aguardar sua edição. Até breve.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu que agradeço sua paciência. você tem rasão. Esses {1} não tem efeito. Porém, ele funciona para o caso `__fo_bar__` veja: https://regexr.com/3t45l

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento fiz a alteração e coloquei um link. Dá uma olhada. Talvez eu não tenha entendido direito o problema.

Comment: Caro Andrei até funciona, mas é mais ou menos, tem a questão do seu permitir coisas como `__a_______` provavelmente, devido ao final do "grupo b", cujo a intenção é evitar, os delimitadadores tem que ser sempre 2, ou seja seguido de qualquer caractere que não seja `_`, o mesmo vale para espaços, cujo o seu regex permite fazer isso `__foo __`, mas vai tentando, tenho certeza que vai sair algo bom :) Obrigado desde já!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tem rasão! Valeu a tentativa...  =/ ... Vou tentar outras coisas, qualquer coisa eu posto aqui. Abraço!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento fiz alterações... Ele não permite `__a_______` e não permite `__foo __` da uma olhada

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento da uma olhada quando você puder. Eu tinha feito alguns testes com o antigo código e não estava funcionando perfeitamente. Mas agora está bem próximo do ideal.